# Redrawing ListView rows on navbar menu click

Tags: android

What is the best way to redraw ListView after specific user action. I am displaying a list of items in a ListView, and the adapter of this list is a basic BaseAdapter. I would like to redraw ListView to display checkbox on each row, this checkbox by default is invisible and I would like it to become visible when user selects an option on navbar menu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must include a boolean field in your adapter `checkVisible` which will be false by default, and after the user makes the selection you go through the whole adapter and make all `checkVisible = true`. 
After that you call `notifyDataSetChanged`.  
Of course inside your adapter class you must hide or show the checkbox depending on the value of checkVisible.

Answer (score 0):

Either do `notifyDataSetChanged()` or just do `listView.invalidate()`